# Consuming rest api using Retrofit

Tags: android, json, rest, post, retrofit

I am working on `android studio`. I am trying to consume `Rest API`. Right now I am using `Postman` for doing my work.

**Body Part**

[image]

**Header Part**

[image]

**Response**

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "global_device_id": "982010",
        "msn": "002998002010",
        "relay_operate": "1"
    }
],
"message": "Auxiliary Relay Status",
"transactionid": "Abdfqwe332432423ti", 
"status": "1"
}
```

**What I have done?**

```
@POST("UIP/on_demand_parameter_read")
Call<UIPResponse> getRelayResponse(@Header("transactionid") String tid, @Header("privatekey") String pk, @Header("Content-Type") String ct,
                              @Body OnDemand onDemand);
```

**OnDemand class**

```
public class OnDemand {

@SerializedName("global_device_id")
@Expose
private String global_device_id;
@SerializedName("type")
@Expose
private String type;



public String getGlobal_device_id() {
    return global_device_id;
}

public void setGlobal_device_id(String global_device_id) {
    this.global_device_id = global_device_id;
}


public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}


public OnDemand(String global_device_id, String type) {
    this.global_device_id = global_device_id;
    this.type = type;
}
}
```

**UIP Response Class**

```
package com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament.model;



import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import java.util.List;


public class UIPResponse
{
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Datum> data = null;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("transactionid")
@Expose
private String transactionid;
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;

public List<Datum> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getTransactionid() {
    return transactionid;
}

public void setTransactionid(String transactionid) {
    this.transactionid = transactionid;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

}

class Datum {

@SerializedName("global_device_id")
@Expose
private String globalDeviceId;
@SerializedName("msn")
@Expose
private String msn;
@SerializedName("relay_operate")
@Expose
private String relayOperate;

public String getGlobalDeviceId() {
    return globalDeviceId;
}

public void setGlobalDeviceId(String globalDeviceId) {
    this.globalDeviceId = globalDeviceId;
}

public String getMsn() {
    return msn;
}

public void setMsn(String msn) {
    this.msn = msn;
}

public String getRelayOperate() {
    return relayOperate;
}

public void setRelayOperate(String relayOperate) {
    this.relayOperate = relayOperate;
}

}
```

**Retrofit Class**

```
public static Retrofit getOnDemandRequest() {
    if (retrofitSignalStrength == null) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .connectTimeout(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(1000,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        retrofitSignalStrength = new
                Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL_STAT)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
    }
    return retrofitSignalStrength;
}
```

Then Finally In my button `onClick` I have done

```
 OnDemand onDemand = new OnDemand(global_device_id, type);

            Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getOnDemandRequest();
            RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);
            Call<UIPResponse> call = retrofitInterface.getRelayResponse(transactionid, privatekey, content_type, onDemand);

            call.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<UIPResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<UIPResponse> call, Response<UIPResponse> response) {

                    boolean isSuccess = false;

                    if(response.isSuccessful())
                    {

                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<UIPResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
```

**Debugging**

While debugging I am getting below log

```
   2020-08-12 14:06:29.551 18991-19117/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: --> POST    http://port:IP/program/on_demand_parameter_read
   2020-08-12 14:06:29.552    18991-19117/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  2020-08-12 14:06:29.552 18991-19117/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 43
  2020-08-12 14:06:29.552 18991-19117/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: transactionid: Abdfqwe332432423ti
  2020-08-12 14:06:29.553 18991-19117/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: privatekey: 87551213232ed334ssdewi
  2020-08-12 14:06:29.555 18991-19117/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: {"global_device_id":"982010","type":"AUXR"}
  2020-08-12 14:06:29.556 18991-19117/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: --> END POST (43-byte body)
  2020-08-12 14:06:30.503 18991-19117/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: <-- 200 http://IP:port/program/on_demand_parameter_read (944ms)
  2020-08-12 14:06:30.504 18991-19117/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  2020-08-12 14:06:30.505 18991-19117/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: Date: Wed, 12 Aug 2020 09:06:31 GMT
  2020-08-12 14:06:30.515 18991-19117/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: Failed to obtain interface by incoming parameters
  2020-08-12 14:06:30.516 18991-19117/com.thumbsol.accuratemobileassetsmanagament D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (49-byte body)
```

I must be missing something that I don't know

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, just add `Log.d("AndroidNetworking", "response received: " + response.toString());` to `onResponse()` callback and `Log.d("AndroidNetworking", "error occured: " + error.toString());` to `onError` callback. And make sure you added Internet Permission to AndroidManifest.xml file: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting

Comment: Did u pass statusBody?

Comment: @navylover yes I did `.addBodyParameter(statusBody)`

Comment: @MariuszBrona I am still unable to see the log :(

Comment: But can your debugger access those Logs (stop at the line where the logs are)?

Comment: @MariuszBrona It's not going inside `getAsJSONArray(new JSONArrayRequestListener()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@FormUrlEncoded`

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("UIP/on_demand_parameter_read")
Call<UIPResponse> getRelayResponse(
    @Header("transactionid") String tid, 
    @Header("privatekey") String pk,
    @Field("global_device_id") String deviceId,  
    @Field("type") String type
);
```

Comment: It does works but still I am unable to go inside the `call.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<UIPResponse>()`

Comment: It's because your json response model `UIPResponse` is wrong. Use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to create your model.

Comment: Yes I have created it with `jsonpojo`.

Comment: I have update my question please see my `UIPResponse`

Comment: Now your response model is correct. What error are you having?

Comment: I am not getting any error. But in my `logcat` I am getting response back.

Comment: Any it's not going inside `call.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<UIPResponse>()`

Comment: Do you mean `onResponse` or `onFailure` is not called?

Comment: both are not called

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219667/discussion-between-bek-and-faisal-qayyum).

Answer (score 0):

If you havent, please add Internet permission in your manifest. You can look it up  https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting

Have you tried using other api? if not, please try it first. Just find some Dummy API in google. this is an example for you https://reqres.in/

I remember that okttp asks for secure api. i can see that yours is not using it. Please refer to this link https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config to trust all connection. You need to add it in your manifest but please read it first. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize the library like it's described here? https://amitshekhar.me/Fast-Android-Networking/adding_fan_to_your_project.html

Also you can enable logging and check in logcat if it's executing the call:

https://amitshekhar.me/Fast-Android-Networking/logging.html

Comment: Yeah I see, and when you debug you are getting onResponse or onFailure event? Maybe use logcat to print throwable or response

Answer (score -2):

Accessing REST API is given in the Android developers guide. Try the example given here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth